# Purpose of the iterator-pattern. Have I understood it right?

Tags: java, php, oop, design-patterns

I have recently tried to understand the so-called Iterator pattern.

Think if have understood it's purpose but I'm still not sure. So please correct me concerning this:

The purpose of the iterator pattern is to abstract away the underlying structure in which the data
are kept. Data-structure can be an array, a tree, a list ...

It's important methods are next() (returns an object), hasNext() (returns a boolean) and remove().

The methods are implemented in a way which is appropriate way for the used data-structure. So the developer
who uses a iterator-implementing-class don't have to care. Just uses the provided methods which are
the same for every iterator-implementing-class.

Have I get it right?

Comment: Read it. http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/iterator-design-pattern/

Comment: Or read this one:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/iterator_pattern.htm

Comment: Why are java **and** php in the tags?

Comment: You've got the return types of `hasNext()` and `next()` the wrong way round: `hasNext()` returns boolean (yes I have a next object or no I don't); `next` returns the next object.

Comment: OOP in PHP is similar to Java. So what you learn in Java you can use PHP too and vice-versa. Not exactly true but more or less.

Comment: @ Andy Turner: Thanks. I've corrected it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your understanding almost covers most of it.
For getting the same in a more technical scenes refer IteratorDesignPattern https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/iterator

Answer (score 2):

What you have summarized is correct. Iterator design pattern hides the underlying complexity of a collection\aggregate by providing an iterator interface in between the collection and the data retriever.

Next,we can take this one level higher by defining an abstraction for the iterator. This means we can write iterators to traverse the same collection in multiple ways. For e.g.: If we have a binary tree collection then we can write three iterators for inorder, postorder and preorder traversals.

Lastly, Iterator pattern allows to have an abstraction for the collection being iterated as well. This implies that one can implement a family of iterators for a family of collections.

One more important thing to note is that an interator knows enough about the inner structure of the collection to be able to iterate it. And that it is the responsibility of the collection instance to create the correct iterator(out of the possible family of iterators) for itself and return it back to the client.

If you are interested in reading more about the iterator pattern, I have explained the above points in depth in a writeup on my blog: http://www.javabrahman.com/design-patterns/iterator-design-pattern-in-java/